# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now()

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error on my function.I'm trying to add a 5 minutes timer between submit on a report by user_id.But for some reasons, I have this error.

**Here is my controller**

```
 public function careerReportCareerSolution(requ $request)
    {

        $report = \App\Reports::create([
                        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                        'username' => $request['username'],
                        'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                        'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
                        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                        'subject' =>$request['subject'],
                        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],
                        'comment' =>$request['comment'],
                        'comment_user' =>$request['comment_user'],
                        'comment_id' =>$request['comment_id'],
                      ]);




        if($report != ""){
            flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
        }else{
            flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
        }

            $reportExists = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>', now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
            ->exists();

            if ($reportExists) {
            // report has been created within 5 minutes
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
        }
        return Redirect::back();


    }
```

Comment: `Carbon::now()`?

Comment: @u_mulder. Hey, can you tell me please where should I put `Carbon::now()`? It's the first time when I'm using this.

Comment: Instead of `now()` obviously.

Comment: Oh, damn. True :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Carbon` facade like this :

```
$reportExists = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
                ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()
                ->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
                ->exists();
```